# Deleting boot options

Tags: boot

I went through and installed wubi through windows 10 for Ubuntu 16.04 but now it is showing 2 choices to boot ubuntu on my start screen. Whenever I select the first choice for Ubuntu it goes directly to Windows 10. Can anyone help me to get rid of this selection?

Comment: Unfortunately, Wubi support ended in 2015. You might be able to uninstall Wubi in the Windows add/remove programs program, which I think deletes all your Ubuntu data (so back it up), and that might remove the entry on your start screen.

Comment: What happened since this http://askubuntu.com/questions/833050/dual-boot-ubuntu-boot-option-still-showing-up-after-uninstall#comment1270782_833050 ? You had plenty of time to learn how to install a proper dual-boot. What's the problem exactly? How can we help?